# Android: keep activity working while in backstack

Tags: android, android-activity, java-websocket

I have an chat app that goes like this :

Activity A  ( main screen showing some general stuff)

Activity B  ( chat room where user can send and receive messages using a WebSocket. I made websocket global, instantiated/reconnected in B, and singleton, since putting in Service seems to be a problem - not reliable, restarting sometimes where the socket it holds becomes null etc. and needs reinitialized etc.)

Activity C  ( user navigates here from B, by clicking on menu. C shows list of participants, owner of the room can kick someone out etc.)

So, when I am in C, I have arrived as A-> B -> C.

When I am in C, I still want B to continue receiving messages, processing them, putting them in messagesadapter etc. That is because, we dont want to lose chat messages ( which are processed in B) while in screen C.

**Question** - when I am in C, will B functionality keep working ? I want to make sure it works. What do I need to ensure it happens reliably ?

Comment: You need a background `Service` that holds the connection to your server. Any other solution is unreliable. If you are having problems getting your `Service` to work, please post a question about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question - when I am in C, will B functionality keep working ? I want
>   to make sure it works. What do I need to ensure it happens reliably ?

To answer your question, your `Activity` B is alive in the task and asynchronous code in that `Activity` will continue to run. Just because the `Activity` is "paused" does not mean that methods cannot be called on it. It is still a live object.

If you only want your chat active when the user has your application in the foreground, then you can do it the way you have described. As soon as your application goes to the background (on arrival of an incoming call, for example), Android can kill the process without warning. When the user returns to your app, Android will create a new process for it and Activity `C` will be reinstantiated. However, `Activity` B will not be reinstantiated.

However, you really need a `Service` to handle socket connections, as it is much more stable.

Comment: Thanks David. I am going ahead with using a Service. Would I need to make it foreground to keep it reliable and make sure it listens and streams audio without losing packets ? as you know, audio packets come very frequently if one is speaking. Luckily for me audio is outgoing only and only text comes in. No audio both ways.

Comment: You can make it a foreground `Service` if the user is interacting with it. This should prevent Android from killing it off. However, you shouldn't make it a foreground `Service` if the user isn't actively using it, that is bad behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Activity B will be paused when your are in C

Google mentions

> **Activity Lifecycle**
>
> Activities in the system are managed as an activity stack. When a new
> activity is started, it is placed on the top of the stack and becomes
> the running activity -- the previous activity always remains below it
> in the stack, and will not come to the foreground again until the new
> activity exits.

To achieve what you want, you need an **IntentService** that will run in the background and you have to register a **broadcast receiver** in activity B to get the messages from the IntentService, then in activity B’s onResume method you could update the UI with the latest messages from the broadcast receiver.

Comment: The reason I didn't choose an IntentService is that - per documentation, it stops as soon as it runs out of work. On my socket, I send audio, text and could receive messages anytime. So, I want it to keep listening and not  let socket stop itself when it is done broadcasting text or audio bytes. Is my understanding wrong for this problem ? Or Should i keep something like a timer alive to not let the IntentService stop by itself ?

Comment: `IntentService` is the wrong approach for this problem, exactly as @techtinkerer states. He should be using a `Service`, but not an `IntentService`

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be create an IntentService which will keep your socket connection alive and keep fetching the messages in the device and when you go back to activity B, in onResume you can fetch all the latest messages form the local storage and update the list adapter.

Comment: `IntentService` is the wrong approach for this problem. `IntentService` is used for short-term background processing, not for a long-lived socket connection to a server. He should be using a `Service`, but not an `IntentService`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to achieve this:

1. When user moves from activity B to activity C, close the socket connection and save the "timestamp" of the last message in preferences. Now when the user is in activity C, your server can push the updates lets say "SYNC" through FCM (or GCM) which tells your app that there is a new update on the server. On receiving this notification from server, call the server pass the "timestamp" stored from the preferences to server. Now, server's job is to return the list of messages after the passed "timestamp". Store all the message in local database. Once the user comes back to the activity B, load the new messages from the local database.
2. Keep the socket connection maintained when moving to another activity. Reconnect to the socket connection on opening of activity C.

You can check our open source android chat sdk code for reference: https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK

Comment: Closing and reopening sockets during activity transition is sloppy and you have windows where you aren't connected at all. This is definitely the wrong approach. OP needs a `Service` with a continuous connection to his server.